# How to retrieve image's url from Firebase's storage?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-storage

I have this code straight from the documentation of Firebase :

```
// Create a reference to the file we want to download
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  var storageRef = firebase.storage();
  var pathReference = storageRef.ref('/' + user + '/profilePicture/' + image.name);

  //var starsRef = storageRef.child('/' + user + '/profilePicture/' + file.name);

  // Get the download URL
  pathReference.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  // Insert url into an <img> tag to "download"
      $scope.imageUrl = url;
      console.log($scope.imageUrl);
  });
```

But I can not figure what to write in my html file in order to get the image showing... Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your result inside a variable of your controller and in ng-src on the HTML.

The best would be to use a service to get the URL and not directly in the controller.

***Controller***

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    // Create a reference to the file we want to download
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    var starsRef = storageRef.child('/' + user + '/profilePicture/' + file.name);

    // Get the download URL
    starsRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
    // Insert url into an <img> tag to "download"
        $scope.imageUrl = url;
    });
}]);
```

***HTML***

```
<img ng-src="{{imageUrl}}"/>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, it displays the css around my picture but the picture itself is **not** showing (yet). I tried a console.log on imageUrl and nothings shows up either. What could be the cause ?

Comment: What you should try to debug is putting a `console.log(url)` and not imageUrl. If you want to debug imageUrl you should do `console.log($scope.imageUrl)`

Comment: My bad I was forgetting to ref the storage. Now the last problem I have is that "file" is not defined. Any idea how I can have this data ?
Otherwise everything works ;)

Comment: This depends of your code. If you don't define a file before file.name will be undefined. This should just be the fileName of your image in firebase storage